# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ("-Xmx1280M")

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, collections, garbage-collection

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "RMI TCP Connection(idle)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I am getting this error my system RAM is 3GB and I have given `-Xmx1280M`. Still, I am getting this error.
In some other machine with 2GB RAM and `-Xmx1280M` option, this error is not coming (Same operation).
What can be the problem? I am using java VisualVM to track which objects are taking memory but heap which is generating at OOME is very big. It is taking very much time to load the heap and "Computing Retained Size" seems to be never ending.

What should I do to recover from OOME?

Comment: what's the difference between those two machines? is one 32bit and the other 64bit? which java versions you have on them? the same/different?

Comment: java version at both machine is 1.6.0_29-b11 and windows 5.1 (xpsp3) 32 bit x86

Comment: Maybe you have another application running on the 3GB server that is taking too much? E.g. SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

The same application that run in 64-bit JVM can consume as much as twice more memory.

Your scenarion is possible if machine where you getting OOME have 64-bit JVM installed and machine where you have no exception is 32-bit JVM.

Hard to answer more without your app in hands.

Comment: java version at both machine is 1.6.0_29-b11 and windows 5.1 (xpsp3) 32 bit x86

Comment: [java] Exception in thread "Thread-29" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
     [java]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:1624)
     [java]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1401)
     [java]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:2840)
     [java]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:468)
     [java]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2534)
     [java]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:1749)
     [java]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2159)

Comment: [java] Exception in thread "TimerQueue" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
     [java]  at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.Timer$1.run(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.Timer$1.run(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]  at javax.swing.Timer.post(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.TimerQueue.postExpiredTimers(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: [java] Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
     [java]  at javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder.getBorderInsets(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.JComponent.getInsets(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.calculateInnerArea(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.sizeChanged(Unknown Source)
     [java]  at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.setAnimationIndex(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsProgressBarUI.setAnimationIndex(Unknown Source)

Comment: Hmm... I have no ideas why do you get OOME. But however on your place I'd check 1) you are working with the same database (if databases are different - the one with huge tables could be an issue)  2) If you are developer of this Java application try to limit the number of rows displayed in JTable of user GUI (by implementing next/previous page mechanism)

Comment: 3) as last resort (if you are developer of this app) try to run application in debugger and pause it before OOME and check what kind of objects are taking space too much space with VisualVM (normal values for space you can get by running VisualVM on working machine).

Comment: 1 hibernate Query is taking 207474 records from MySql table that could be the problem but not sure because heap dump which is generated at OOME in jVisualVm is not opened i have to get heap dump again !

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown server, remove all caches and restart. When then the problem persists it must a different system configuration, database or so, and might be retraceable to some wrong coding.

Answer (score 0):

Set your maximum and minimum heap to the same size (-Xms1280m -Xmx1280m) so that the jvm will attempt to grab the full amount on startup. It maybe that on one machine there is not a large enough contiguous chunk of memory.

I have seen virus checkers and other software prevent the JVM from finding contiguous chunks even when the is a large amount of free ram.